# Wordpress update does not proceed

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins, elementor

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3KDI5.png)

I tried to update Wordpress to version 6.2.2, however, it did not proceed and stopped at the line "Unzipping Update".

I tried to install Wordpress v6.2.2 on the computer but it didn't work. I also tried increasing php time and memory, and once again, it didn't work.
I already used the "Fix Another Update In Progress" plugin, and it didn't help me.

Answer (score 0):

You mention about increasing php time and memory.
Did you check your server error logs?
Did you get a PHP Fatal error: Allowed memory of x number of bytes (tried to allocte x bytes) in, or similar message?
If so, you need to change the memory limit in the php.ini file for your server.
If in safe_mode and any other restrictions aren't enabled, the the php_value via .htaccess or in a .user.ini for CGI setups may help?
Also, try deleting the .maintenance file, as your update has failed and this file will sit in your route directory. Once deleted, and your happy that the memory limit has been increased successfully, try running the update again.
Some information on the .maintenance file below:

https://quadlayers.com/wordpress-update-failed-error/

Good luck!